# What is the significance of complex turning points?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I think I know the significance of complex roots, if you have ${y = x^2 + 1}$ you will solve the equation ${x^2 + 1 = 0}$ which will give you ${i}$ and ${-i}$. This means that if you have the complex function ${f(z) =z^2+1}$, it is true that ${f(i) =0}$ and ${f(-i) =0}$. So a complex root of a real function gives you the root of the same function with a complex domain.

I was wondering if there was a similiar sort of significance to complex turning points. For example, if you have the function ${f(x) = 1/3x^3 + x}$ and you take the derivative to get ${g(x) = x^2 + 1}$, setting this derivative equal to zero and solving it gives the answers ${i} $ and ${-i} $. Is there any significance to these complex values? Do they tell you anything about the function but with a complex domain like complex roots do?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do have significance, but it's a bit harder to understand because it's not as easy to visualise complex functions.

To provide a little bit of a half-way point of understanding, we can look at multivariate functions, specifically functions that take two real inputs and give one real output (i.e. functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$). With these functions, we look at their partial derivatives with respect to the two inputs, and when both derivatives are equal to zero we get a critical point - which might be a local maximum, minimum, or a saddle point which is sort of like the 3D version of an inflection point.

[image: Graphs of three different 3-dimensional functions showing local maxima, minima and saddle points.]
(Image taken from [LibreTexts Mathematics](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/UCD_Mat_21C%3A_Multivariate_Calculus/13%3A_Partial_Derivatives/13.7%3A_Extreme_Values_and_Saddle_Points))

We can, in some respects, treat complex numbers like points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a bit of extra structure, so a function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is like a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, or two separate functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ representing the real and imaginary parts respectively.

When you take the derivative, though, it might be more helpful to imagine a vector field - at every point $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$, you have an arrow pointing in the direction of $\frac{df}{dz}$ - if $\frac{df}{dz} = -1 + 2z$ then that arrow points one unit to the left and two units upwards, for example. These vectors show you the "flow" of the function, i.e. they point to the direction where it's growing the most and their size tells you how much it's growing, just like how the derivative of a real function tells you how much the function is sloping.

In this context, a derivative of zero represents a point with no flow - if you dropped a marble exactly at that spot, it wouldn't move anywhere. Calling that point a "maximum" or "minimum" or "saddle point" doesn't make as much sense, though, because there isn't a single overarching definition of what "bigger" or "smaller" means in the complex numbers.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply, that makes a lot of sense :)